# Error when installing cryptography 1.8.1 module

Tags: python, visual-studio, cryptography, paramiko

I have 64 bit Windows 7, and 32 bit python 2.7.13 installed.
I also installed VC for python 2.7.

I'm trying to install `paramiko 2.1.2`. It gives an error when installing `cryptography 1.8.1`.

Therefore I try to install `cryptography 1.8.1` separatley. But when I try to do it it gives the following error:

```
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_openssl.c(434) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open in
clude file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\b_ozel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\
Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you install OpenSSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind installing the cryptography package from binary instead of compiling from source, make sure you have a pip version above 8.

The pip version that comes with python 2.7 is quite old (1.x) and that only understands installing cryptography (and paramiko) from source.

To upgrade pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thank you, pip solved it. But I don't understand why `python setup.py install` won't work with cryptography 1.8.1, I downloaded the zip file from official python website.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install `cryptography` using `pip` instead of manually installation.